# Item list in two columns

Tags: enumitem

Any ideas on how to make an item list with the following form:

(a) Chemistry .................... (b) Physics

(c) Mathematics ..............   (d) Biology

It seems to me that I can use `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}` to make the list horizontal, but that affects the entire document and I just want one of many lists to appear as I mentioned at the beginning of the post.

Comment: Take a look at the tasks package.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for. @leandriis